# Add word at caret to dictionary using the keyboard

Tags: sublime-text-3, spell-check

When using spell checking in Sublime Text 3, it is possible to right click on a misspelled/underlined word and from the context menu, add it to the dictionary. Is there a way to do this using the keyboard without involving the mouse?

[image: context menu spelling suggestions]

The [official documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/spell_checking.html) mentions the `add_word` command, but there is no default keybinding that uses it, and it requires that the word to add be specified as an argument - i.e. it doesn't add the word under the caret.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer would be to open the context menu with the keyboard (some keyboards have a dedicated button for it, for example between the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> on Windows. Then it is just a case of using the arrow keys to select the Add word menu item and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

This could obviously be done with less keypresses using a custom keybinding, which is where the `add_word` command mentioned in the documentation would come in handy.

However, as keybindings can't use the text under the cursor or the selection as an argument, a small Python plugin would need to be created for this. (There are exceptions where the command being executed supports it, like `insert_snippet` supporting a `$SELECTION` placeholder in the `contents` argument.)

Here is how to create a Python script that will add the words at the cursors to the dictionary:

1. From the `Tools` menu -> `Developer` -> `New Plugin`
2. Paste in the following:

   ```
   import sublime
   import sublime_plugin

   class AddWordsAtCursorsToDictionaryCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
       def run(self, edit):
           for sel in self.view.sel():
               region = None
               if sel.empty():
                   region = self.view.word(sel.begin())
               else:
                   region = sel
               word = self.view.substr(region)
               self.view.run_command('add_word', { 'word': word })
   ```
3. Save it, in the default folder it suggests, as something like `add_word.py` - the file extension is very important, the base name itself isn't.
4. Goto `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings - User` or `Key Bindings` depending on which version of ST3 you have.
5. Enter the following:

   ```
   { "keys": ["f8"], "command": "add_words_at_cursors_to_dictionary" }
   ```
6. If the file was previously empty, ensure the text above is surrounded by square brackets. i.e. `[` and `]`. Basically, it needs to be a valid JSON file, containing an array of keybindings.
7. Save it
8. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> to add the word at the text caret(s) to the dictionary. (Obviously, you can change this to whatever key you desire in the relevant step.)